# Alternative to IsolatedStorageSettings for MonoTouch

Tags: c#, .net, mono, xamarin.ios, isolatedstorage

I am attempting to recreate an Application which I originally made for Windows Phone 7.8 - When we originally made it; we used IsolatedStorageSettings to store information about the user.

When we attempted to do this using MonoDevelop/MonoTouch we noticed that it didn't recognise IsolatedStorageSettings and therefore has caused a large problem for us when creating the Application for iOS.

The code we used for Windows phone to create the storage:

```
public IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
```

What other ways are there for us to store settings within our application using Isolated Storage. We have looked into using 'IsolatedStorageFile' though, using this method seems to cause a large amount of hassle.

The information we are trying to save includes;
-First Name
-Last Name
-Tutors Name
-Number of times a button was pressed

How would we go about doing this using IsolatedStorageFile or another IsolatedStorage method?

Answer (score 2):

This type never made it into the *regular* framework but it does not mean you can't use it.

The source code for Moonlight (Mono's implementation of Silverlight) [`IsolatedStorageSettings`](https://github.com/mono/moon/blob/master/class/System.Windows/System.IO.IsolatedStorage/IsolatedStorageSettings.cs) is available. It's small, fully managed and can be included inside your own applications (or built in a separate assembly for reuse accross projects).

It might require a few modifications since Silverlight API for `System.IO.IsolatedStorage` is not 100% compatible with the "desktop" version of the .NET framework (which Xamarin products follows). OTOH it should be very small changes (the source itself being very small).

Comment: How would I go ahead and make any modifications required so it can be used?

Comment: Copy the source file inside your project then compile, look at errors, fix, compile... rince and repeat :)

Comment: Thanks for the help; I shall have a look into this.